# parsing a tail file to process commands

Tags: bash, tail

I have found some info on this, but not enough to get me going with this project.  I have limited bash experience, trying to learn.

I have a log file that I would like to read (`tail`) and process lines as they come in based on timestamp in the log.

Log example: from a `tail -f filename.txt | grep --line-buffered RXKEY,MAIN`:

```
20230913200618,12345,RXKEY,MAIN
20230913200620,12345,RXKEY,MAIN
20230913200627,12345,RXKEY,MAIN
20230913200629,12345,RXKEY,MAIN
```

(Timestamp,id,type,location)

I would like to read this file and perform an action, if the last entry was X amount of seconds before the previous entry.  IE, if 2 logs hit in 4 or 5 seconds apart, run a command locally.  Then keep monitoring for future logs and repeat as needed.

I have the log working but not sure how to read the timestamps and then process an action.

Comment: You would need to use a scripting language, which could replace both `tail` and `grep`.  What do you know?  `awk`?  `python`?  `node.js`?  `perl`?  Any would work.

Comment: as an aside for bash resources, [devhints](https://devhints.io/bash) useful as a cheatsheet, `man bash` is good to skim over just so you know whats available, and the [google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html) is surprisingly good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe `grep` into `while read`, which lets you loop over each line received.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare allow_difference=5
declare last=

# 'while read -r' to prevent backslashes from being interpreted
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192786/what-is-the-meaning-of-read-r
tail -f filename.txt | grep --line-buffered RXKEY,MAIN | while read -r line; do
    # read into array 'linearray', splitting on ',' by setting
    # the IFS (how bash chooses to split word boundaries)
    IFS=',' read -ra linearray <<< "$line"
    # [[ -z "$somevariable" ]] checks if the variable is empty
    # if its empty, then we havent set a last time yet, so set it and continue the while loop
    if [[ -z "$last" ]]; then
        last="${linearray[0]}"
        continue
    fi
    # get the difference between the current time and the last time
    # $(()) for bash arithmetic
    difference="$((linearray[0] - last))"
    # if the difference is smaller than the allowed difference, then run some command
    if ((difference < allow_difference)); then
        echo "difference between ${last} and ${linearray[0]} is ${difference}, running command"
        # could add some other command here...
    fi
    last="${linearray[0]}"
done
```

Tried to comment more than usual as you said you're new to `bash` but let me know if something isn't understandable.

```
 $ ./script 
difference between 20230913200618 and 20230913200620 is 2, running command
^C
```

Comment: Thank you.  I believe I understand most of this.  But, how does the loop repeat and the var $last be cleared for the new line when it comes in?  I see where it is set, but should it be cleared as well at the end of the script, or is $last cleared somehow in your code?

Comment: Since `tail -f` 'follows' the logfile, it continues running forever, so does `grep`, and the `read -r line` continues to return a zero exit code each time it gets a line, which acts like a `while true` loop. So, the `while` just keeps sitting there, waiting for `grep` to spit out a line, and then runs the loop body once when it gets a new line

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right on the `$last` not being set, updated it so it gets set at the end of the loop. That way it can compare to the previous time the loop body gets run

Comment: As an example of how the `while read` works, try running something like this in your shell: `{ while true; do date; sleep 1; done } | while read -r line; do echo "hi, I got a line: $line"; done`

Comment: Ah, hm. That might be differing versions of `readarray` on mac or an old version of bash. You can use `read` instead and set `IFS`(internal field separator, how bash chooses to split strings):

`IFS=',' read -ra linearray <<< "$line"`. Updated answer above

Comment: Okay, with the IFS it is working and all looks good.  Thank you for the fast answers and the detailed info.  Very helpful, much appreciated.